# Reassigning non-absolute variables in OSX's assembler

Tags: macos, assembly, clang, llvm, gnu-assembler

The following assembler directives, when compiled with clang on OSX, produce an error:

```
  .set link,0
test:
  .int link
  .set link,test
test2:
  .int link
  .set link,test2
```

The error:

```
$ clang test.s
test.s:7:13: error: invalid reassignment of non-absolute variable 'link'
  .set link,test2
            ^
```

I want to use `link` in a macro as a variable that keeps track of the last defined word, to build a linked list (as in [JONESFORTH](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nornagon/jonesforth/master/jonesforth.S)).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't redefine normal symbols. The way I see it, you have two choices. Either you allocate a local label number to store your link address (as these can be redefined) or you use preprocessed assembly. For both cases, you probably want to use a macro to declare your nodes.

Example:

```
.macro declare_node list_id
.ifndef link_head_\list_id
link_head_\list_id : .int 0
.else
.int \list_id\()b-4
.endif
\list_id :
.endm

test:
declare_node 100
.int 42 # node data

test2:
declare_node 100
.int 314 # node data

test3:
declare_node 101
.int 173 # node data

test4:
declare_node 101
.int 141 # node data
```

Here, a numerical list id is used as the local label, so you can declare multiple lists.

Comment: In addition to Jesters answer, I believe for jonesforth OS X uses type `.long` instead of `.int` (...or at least at one time was...)

Comment: I actually don't care about exporting the symbol, I just want to keep track of where the last node was. At the end I take the last value (the head of the list) and bind that to a symbol (LATEST).

Comment: (My solution was to switch to gcc's gas, which doesn't have a problem with this construction.)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (jonesforth). I have not found out why apples assembler doesn't allow to redefine symbols, but it is what it is.

I worked around this by manually passing the last defined word as an argument to the defword macro. It's ugly as hell, and error prone.

```
    .macro defcode name, length, flags, name, link
    .const_data
    .balign 8
    .globl name_\name
name_\name :
    .quad \link             // link
    .byte \flags+\length    // flags + length byte
    .ascii \name            // the name
    .balign 8               // padding to next 8 byte boundary
    .globl \name
\name :
    .quad code_\name        // codeword
    .text
    .balign 8
    .globl code_\name
code_\name :                // assembler code follows
    .endmacro
```

Then call the macro like

```
    defcode "BRANCH",6,0,BRANCH,name_TICK
    ... 
    NEXT

    defcode "0BRANCH",7,0,ZBRANCH,name_BRANCH
    ...
    NEXT
```

I'd be super excited to learn about better ways to handle it.